# How to use reflection to get/set the value of a property?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use reflection to cycle through all of the properties in a given class and perform a conversion on all DateTime properties it finds.

However I am getting an error {"Object does not match target type."}

How do I get the value of the given property and set its value?

My code:

```
var properties = myObj.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in properties) {
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)) {
        DateTime? test = prop.GetValue(this);
        // Do conversion on test
        // Do something like prop.SetValue(??) with the new value 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the parameter that you are passing to `GetValue` - it needs to be `myObj`, not `this`.

In addition, you need to cast the result of the call to `DateTime?` on assignment:

```
DateTime? test = (DateTime?)prop.GetValue(this);
```

Comment: It should be possible to handle DateTime and DateTime? together. You can always unbox a value type T to `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @mikez Edited, thanks! Unboxing a non-nullable into a nullable worked perfectly. I'm almost sure that I tried this a long time ago, when nullable types came out, and it did not work. But perhaps I was doing it the wrong way.